# XTestFakeKeyEvent and unicode (problems with Qt)

Tags: qt, unicode, x11, utf-16, vala

What my program needs to do is simulate key press to insert a unicode character. I use gnome-based desktop and it works everywhere, in all gtk apps I tested, google chrome. But it doesn't work right in telegram and qtransmission (only Qt apps that I've tested). Most symbols below 0xD7FF work good, even composed, but I haven't found anything bigger than 0xD7FF that works. So emojis mostly don't work. Though it's possible to insert these chars with copy-and-paste.

I'm sorry that my code is in Vala, but it's not so much different from C. So here it is:

```
void Insert (unichar symbol) {
    unowned X.Display display = Gdk.X11.get_default_xdisplay ();

    int max = 0, min = 0;
    display.keycodes (ref min, ref max);

    int keysyms_per_symcode = 0;
    var keysyms = display.get_keyboard_mapping ((uchar) min, max - min, ref keysyms_per_symcode);

    int keycode = min;

    unichar[] symbols = new unichar[4];
    ulong size = symbol.fully_decompose(true, symbols);

    for (ulong i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        unichar c = symbols[i];

        string code = "U%04x".printf(c);
        ulong new_keysyms[] = {X.string_to_keysym (code)};

        message ("code %s ; keycode %d ; keysym %lu", code, keycode, new_keysyms[0]);

        XChangeKeyboardMapping (display, keycode, 1, new_keysyms, 1);

        XTest.fake_key_event (display, keycode, true, 0);
        XTest.fake_key_event (display, keycode, false, 100);
        display.flush ();
    }

    ulong original[] = {0};
    XChangeKeyboardMapping (display, keycode, 1, original, 1);
    display.flush ();
}
```

I think it may be related to UTF-16. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: So somewhere on xorg website I think they say program developer decide how to translate keysym. I guess it's not fixable then because it's how it's done in Qt.